# Get File encoding ASCII or EBCDIC with java

Tags: java, file, encoding, ascii, ebcdic

I have a file which extension is **.b3c** i want to know if it's encoded in ASCII or EBCDIC using java jow can I achieve that please.

Help is needed.

Thanks

Comment: There is no 100 % solution to this (unless you know some file contents in advance). You will have to use some heuristics.

Comment: @Henry what do you mean by **heuristics** ?

Comment: Something like Andreas proposed below.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the text file contains multiple lines of text, check for the *newline* character.

In ASCII, lines end with an `LF` / `\n` / `0x0a`. Sure, on Windows there's also a `CR`, but we can ignore that part.

In EBCDIC, lines end with an `NL` / `\025` / `0x15`.

ASCII text files will not contain a `0x15` / `NAK`, and EBCDIC text files will not contain a `0x0a` / `SMM`, so look for both:

- If only one of them is found, you know the character set.
- If both are found, the file is a binary file, and not a text file, so reject the file.
- If neither is found, the file could have just one line of text, in which case further analysis might be needed. Hopefully that won't be the case for here, so the simple test done so far should be enough.

Comment: hello @Andreas, so how do i read/recognise those characters in Java 8/11 ?

Comment: Hello @Andres how do I recognise those characters in my java program? I tried to read the file with BufferReader, but i can see those characters...

Comment: @Bizi You can't use [`BufferedReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) since you don't know the character set yet. You need to read the file as a binary file, i.e. using [`FileInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html).